# How can I initialize a UITextField Variable?

Tags: swift, variables, initialization, uitextfield

I would like to have a variable that tells me which Textfield was just edited. Therefor the variable needs to has the Type UITextField. But how can i initialize it?

```
var whichTextFieldWasEditited = UITextField

init() { }
```

Comment: you can also create IBOutlet

Comment: It's difficult to tell what do you mean. Do you mean across the entire application? The same viewController?

Comment: The delegate methods tell you which one was edited.

Comment: Sorry, i mean the same viewController

Comment: I want to use the information, which one was edited, outside the delegate methods.

Comment: Then set a viewController property inside the delegate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All UITextFields have protocol that you can conform to.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate

The protocol has  6 different methods, the one you're looking for is textFieldDidEndEditing

The easiest way to differentiate between UITextFields is to assign them tags. All UIViews (and subclasses) have a tag such that they can be identified.

To be able to use this protocol method to your advantage you need to set the UITextField's delegate to "self" which in your case will be the view controller, as well as set the tags for the UITextFields

To tie it all in together

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

     let textField1 = UITextField() //() is the constructor for the object
     let textField2 = UITextField() 

     init(){ //some generic init
        super.init()
        textField1.delegate = self
        textField1.tag = 1
        textField2.delegate = self
        textField2.tag = 2
     }

     //protocol method
     func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ sender: UITextField){
         //since the sender is of UITextField 
         if sender.tag == 1 { //it's textField1
             //do something
         }
         if sender.tag == 2 { //it's textField2
             //do something
         }
      }
 }
```

Note: This is just a skeleton example, the important take aways is that your class needs to conform to the UITextFieldDelegate, you need to assign your text field's delegates to yourself, you need to set their tags and then you can differentiate between them in the protocol methods.

Comment: I found my mistake. I did create a delegate and an extension of the ViewController but my mistake was that i tried to source the working process out of the textFieldDidEndEditing function